# runtime error while locating an excel file using exceldriver in testcomplete

Tags: jscript, testcomplete

I'm trying to import data from an external excel file using the ExcelDriver in TestComplete. The file is stored in `C:\Users\Public\Documents\MyTestCompleteFiles\Data-Driven Testing\DD_Book.xlsx`.

Here is the snippet:

```
inputDriver = DDT.ExcelDriver("C:\Users\Public\Documents\MyTestCompleteFiles\Data-Driven Testing\dataBook.xlsx", "dataSheet", true);
```

When I run the script, I get a JScript runtime error saying that the excel worksheet does not exist.

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JScript you need to double slashes in string variables. Here is the correct code:

```
inputDriver = DDT.ExcelDriver("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\MyTestCompleteFiles\\Data-Driven Testing\\dataBook.xlsx", "dataSheet", true);
```